# Understanding Flutter Render Engine

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The docs [here](https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-update-listviews-dynamically) about how to update a `ListView` say:

> In Flutter, if you were to update the list of widgets inside a
>   setState(), you would quickly see that your data did not change
>   visually. This is because when setState() is called, the Flutter
>   rendering engine looks at the widget tree to see if anything has
>   changed. When it gets to your ListView, it performs a == check, and
>   determines that the two ListViews are the same. Nothing has changed,
>   so no update is required.
>
> For a simple way to update your ListView, create a new List inside of
>   setState(), and copy the data from the old list to the new list.

I don't get how the Render Engine determines if there are any changes in the Widget Tree in this case.

AFAICS, we care calling `setState`, which marks the `State` object as dirty and asks it to rebuild. Once it rebuilds there will be a new `ListView`, won't it? So how come the `==` check says it's the same object?

Also, the new `List` will be internal to the `State` object, does the Flutter engine compare all the objects inside the `State` object? I thought it only compared the `Widget` tree.

So, basically I don't understand how the Render Engine decides what it's going to update and what's going to ignore, since I can't see how creating a new `List` sends any information to the Render Engine, as the docs says the Render Engine just looks for a new `ListView`... And AFAIK a new `List` won't create a new `ListView`.

Comment: It's a theoretical question I had when reading the docs. No actual code involved

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Flutter isn't made only of [Widgets](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Widget-class.html).

When you call `setState`, you mark the **Widget** as dirty. But this Widget isn't actually what you render on the screen. 
Widgets exist to create/mutate [RenderObjects](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderObject-class.html); it's these RenderObjects that draw your content on the screen.

The link between RenderObjects and Widgets is done using a new kind of Widget: [RenderObjectWidget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RenderObjectWidget-class.html) (such as [LeafRenderObjectWidget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/LeafRenderObjectWidget-class.html))

Most widgets provided by Flutter are to some extent a RenderObjectWidget, including ListView.

A typical RenderObjectWidget example would be this:

```
class MyWidget extends LeafRenderObjectWidget {
  final String title;

  MyWidget(this.title);

  @override
  MyRenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return new MyRenderObject()
      ..title = title;
  }

  @override
    void updateRenderObject(BuildContext context, MyRenderObject renderObject) {
      renderObject
        ..title = title;
    }
}
```

This example uses a widget to create/update a RenderObject. It's not enough to notify the framework that there's something to repaint though.

To make a RenderObject repaint, one must call `markNeedsPaint` or `markNeedsLayout` on the desired renderObject.

This is usually done by the RenderObject itself using custom field setter this way:

```
class MyRenderObject extends RenderBox {
  String _title;
  String get title => _title;
  set title(String value) {
    if (value != _title) {
      markNeedsLayout();
      _title = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the `if (value != previous)`.

This check ensures that when a widget rebuilds without changing anything,  Flutter doesn't relayout/repaint anything.

It's due to this exact condition that mutating `List` or `Map` doesn't make `ListView` rerender. It basically has the following:

```
List<Widget> _children;
List<Widget> get children => _children;
set children(List<Widget> value) {
  if (value != _children) {
    markNeedsLayout();
    _children = value;
  }
}
```

But it implies that if you *mutate* the list instead of creating a new one, the RenderObject will not be marked as needing a relayout/repaint. Therefore there won't be any visual update.

Comment: Interesting... Then the documentation is wrong when it says the Render Engine checks for equality in the `ListView` object... In fact the `ListView` cheks for equality in its contents... Also it's interesting to see there's mutation on the `RenderObject`, Flutter docs speaks so much about immutability, I thought it was all immutable

Comment: It does both, the `children` check is a later step. It you returned the same `ListView` instance, it wouldn't even reach the `children` check and abort before.

Comment: `RenderObject` being mutable is fine, you almost never have to create one yourself. Flutter handles the mutability so that we don't have to.

Comment: What do you mean by "you  returned the same `ListView`"? AFAIK, I only create a new `ListView` in a `build` method, and because of immutability, it's always a new one

Comment: There are many situations onto which we reuse a widget instance. `const` constructors for example, or the `child`/`children` argument. When a widget that receives a child does a setState, it doesn't actually rebuild that child.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, these are all new information to me... It will be nice to have an article explaining (at least I didn't find one) in details what behaviors `setState()` triggers, in depth, because the more you explain to me, the more doubts I have hahaha

Comment: Good idea. I noted it and will likely make an article about this

Comment: AFAICS, a `Stateful` widget will trigger a `build` method if some code calls `setState` in that `Stateful` Widget.... Then I thought the `build` method would create all the new widgets and pass them all their children all over again.. So `setState` doesn't trigger `build`?

Comment: FYI, I am a senior Android developer starting to learn Flutter/Dart, if you guys need a noob to read stuff and say how it sounds to a noob, don't hesitate to contact me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184223/discussion-between-remi-rousselet-and-mfeinstein).